# Yocto: undefined reference to ´of_find_mipi_dsi_device´

Tags: linux, stm32, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

Currently I am working with stm32mp1 board and developing Yocto image for the Kirkstone version. I have the following build configuration for the baord.

```
   Build Configuration:
   BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
   BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
   NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
   TARGET_SYS           = "arm-emt_eglfs-linux-gnueabi"
   MACHINE              = "emsbc-argon"
   DISTRO               = "emt-eglfs"
   DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.3"
   TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
   TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
   DISTRO_CODENAME      = "kirkstone"
   ACCEPT_EULA_emsbc-argon = "1"
   GCCVERSION           = "11.%"
   PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-stm32mp-argon"
   meta-emtrion-emsbc-argon = "HEAD:7c4912ff0cecc10281ca52a18402d0a29d9ad6ec"
   meta-emtrion         = "HEAD:254f385f1d5b8deb0723a0dc4fdb996dd64661b1"  
   meta                 = "HEAD:f7766da462905ec67bf549d46b8017be36cd5b2a"
   meta-oe              
   meta-initramfs       
   meta-multimedia      
   meta-python          
   meta-networking      
   meta-webserver       
   meta-filesystems     
   meta-perl            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
   meta-qt5             = "HEAD:5b71df60e523423b9df6793de9387f87a149ac42"
   meta-st-stm32mp      = "HEAD:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
   meta-st-openstlinux  = "HEAD:cb736b403d0fef2a02390695613b6b4bb13ca1b7"
   meta-gnome           
   meta-xfce            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
```

I have the following Error:

```
ld: drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.o: in function `edt_ft5x06_ts_probe':
| edt-ft5x06.c:(.text+0x15a4): undefined reference to `of_find_mipi_dsi_device_by_node'
| make[1]: *** [/home/hico/work/emtrion-beta-test/build-argon/tmp-glibc/work-shared/emsbc-argon/kernel-source/Makefile:1080: vmlinux] Error 1
| make: *** [/home/hico/work/emtrion-beta-test/build-argon/tmp-glibc/work-shared/emsbc-argon/kernel-source/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

I have a custom recipe named as m4examples.bb and the error is coming from this recipe. Does anyone have any idea for this error?

In the following link you can find the logfile. [undefined reference error logfile](https://pastebin.com/x6V4US5Z)

Comment: the first error in the log file is: init/initramfs.o: warning: objtool: missing symbol for section .text. Looks like some #include could be messed up (missing?)

Comment: Maybe you should show us the recipe that is causing the problem.